# MATLAB: Plotting different numerical approximation in one plot

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical-methods

I have the following matlab code for approximating a differential equation via the Euler-method:

```
% Eulermethod

a=0;
b=0.6;
Steps=6;
dt=(b-a)/Steps;
x=zeros(Steps+1,1);

x(1,1)=1;
y=zeros(Steps+1,1);

for i=1:Steps
    x(i+1,1)=x(i,1)+dt*(x(i,1)*x(i,1)+1);
end
plot(x)
```

I want to be able to plot the solution plot for several different values of Steps in one plot and have the x-axis go from 0 to 0.6 instead of from for example 1 to 100 000 etc. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `hold on` command this will allow you achieve multiple plots on the same figure. Similarly, if you separate your data into `x` and `y` vectors, you can plot them against eachother by passing 2 vectors to `plot` instead of just one. For example

```
figure
hold on
for i=1:m
    x = [];
    y = [];
    %% code to populate your vectors
    plot(x,y)
end
```

You should now see all your plots simultanesously on the same figure. If you want `x` to be composed of `n` equally spaced elements between 0 and 0.6, you could use the `linspace` command:

```
 x = linspace(0.0,0.6,n);
```

In order to distinguish your plots, you can pass an extra paramter to the function .For example

```
 plot(x,y,'r+')
```

will plot the data as a series of red `+` symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried implementing what you said but failed miserably :p The issue is that the vectors get different dimensions. I want both of them to be in one chart with the x-axis going from 0 to 0.6

`% Eulermethod`
`format long`
`a=0;`
`b=0.6;`
`Steps1=6;`
`dt1=(b-a)/Steps1;`
`x=zeros(Steps1+1,1);`

`Steps2=100000;`
`dt2=(b-a)/Steps2;`
`y=zeros(Steps2+1,1);`

`x(1,1)=1;`
`y(1,1)=1;`

`hold on`
`for i=1:Steps1`
`    x(i+1,1)=x(i,1)+dt*(x(i,1)*x(i,1)+1);`
`end`

`for i=1:Steps2`
`    y(i+1,1)=y(i,1)+dt*(y(i,1)*y(i,1)+1);`
`end`

`%plot?`

Comment: I'm new to the formatting in the comment section so sorry for the horribleness

Answer (score 0):

Plot can take more arguments: plot(x_axis,values,  *modifiers*);
If *x-axis* is a vector of M elements, values can be a matrix of MxN elements, each of which are drawn with a separate color.